# sum of all integer in range which are divisible by k

Tags: java

Is there a way to calculate the sum in this range that is divisible by k
with time complexity: O(1)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    long a = in.nextLong();
    long b = in.nextLong();
    long k = in.nextLong();
    long SUM=0;
    for (long i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        if(i%k==0){
            SUM+=i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(SUM);
}
```

Comment: Yes there is a way to use a formula to basically do it in O(1). Basically calculate the smallest and largest numbers that are divisible by `k` and are in the range (could already be `a` and `b`) and then calculate the sum of fitting values in that range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O(1) would basically mean you need a formula to calculate that sum.

Considering the formula for all numbers in a range is `(start + end) * numValues / 2` you could do the following:

```
//if a already is a multiple of k just use it, otherwise find the next larger one
int start = a % k == 0? a : a + k - a%k;

//find the divisible of k that is equal to b or the next smaller one
int end = b - b%k;
    
//the number of values is the number of times k fits into the range 
int num = ((end - start) / k) + 1;
    
//apply the formula
int sum = (start + end) * num / 2;
```

Comment: @StephenC oh yeah, that would have been nice ... my bad :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple observation can help you compute the required sum.
For example, lets have a range `[a, b] = [150, 200]` and `k` be **7**. So, the first number divisible by `k` in [a, b] would be (154):

```
long left = (a%k == 0) ? a : (a/k) * k + k;
```

And the last number divisible by `k` in [a, b] would be (196):

```
long right = (b%k == 0) ? b : (b/k) * k;
```

Now if we breakdown the multiples of `k` in [a, b], we can observe a pattern as follows:

```
154 = 154
161 = 154 + 1*7
168 = 154 + 2*7
175 = 154 + 3*7
182 = 154 + 4*7
189 = 154 + 5*7
196 = 154 + 6*7
```

The number of multiples of `k` in [a+k, b] can be easily calculated using:

```
long count = (right - left) / k;
```

And the sum of *1+2+3 ... +count* would be:

```
long firstNsum = (count * (count + 1)) / 2;
```

And our final sum would  be:

```
long SUM = left + (left*count) + firstNsum * k;
```

which would be equal to: `154 + (154 * 6) + 21 * 7 = 1225` in our case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to compute the answer using a loop, the solution will be `O(N)` for some `N` that depends on the inputs.

**However**, you don't need to compute the answer using a loop.  The alternative is to do some maths and work out an algebraic formula for the sum.  Once you have the formula, you can compute the sum in `O(1)`.

Hint: the sum is going to be a multiple of `k`.

Answer (score 0):

starting with the well known formula for sum of all positive integers up to `n`:

```
sum = n * (n+1) / 2
```

easy to change it to all numbers in range `[i,j]` - basically the sum of all numbers up to `j` minus the sum of all numbers up to `i-1`.

Now we need to adapt it to only numbers divisible by `k`:

1. divide start by `k` rounding UP
2. divide end by `k` rounding down
3. multiply sum of above range by `k`

(can be done only with integer operations, no conditional needed, but eventually for input data validation: `k` positive, valid range)